# Multiple Scatter Plots for different parameters - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, scatter-plot

I'm struggling to plot different scatter plots on one graph for a set of data in a data frame so that it'll show price versus area for different property types: Residential,  Commercial and Industrial.

The Dataframe currently looks like this:

```
property_type   area    actual_worth    
Commercial      59.92   161250.0
Commercial      50.00   160000.0
Residential     40.50   123400.0
Industrial      35.49   61250.0
Industrial      24.30   125000.0
Commercial      90.12   69700.0
```

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) for easy control of these types of plots.

Here's a very simple example based on your sample data:

```
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='property_type')
g.map(sns.scatterplot, 'area', 'actual_worth')
```

[image]